# Bug with C++14 "All time Questions Asked"

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

If you take a look at the overview of the [C++14 Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b14/topusers) that have been asked so far, you are told that the count is around 30, while on [the tag main page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) I can see 11 pages with a total of **at least** 300 Questions¹.

I think that this is related to the deletion of the [c++1y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1y) tag, that has now become a synonym of the new [c++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) tag, but it looked kind of odd anyway.

---

¹ 10 pages * 30 posts/page + 1 page = over 300

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261668/why-do-the-printf-synonyms-retain-some-vestiges-independent-existence

Comment: Well, I've given the system a good kick, and it is sticking with `29`... so definitely something amiss. Will investigate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was reporting reality; if you had visited the questions, only 29 would have been tagged [c++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) - the rest would have **only** been tagged [c++1y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1y). We *show* the [c++1y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1y), but it is not automatic that creating a synonym flattens one tag into the other. That option *exists*, though! [c++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) should now report correctly with the 322+ questions.

Comment: That was a fast fix ;) Edit: the all time score thing is still broken tho :O

Comment: @Theolodis which "all time score thing" ? the users? Caching...

Comment: on the [tag:c++14] page, when you look at the tab "top users", there is a listing of the top score users. But yeah, might be caching issue...

Comment: @Theolodis see bottom of page: "Only non community-wiki questions and answers are included in these totals (updated daily)" - should be fixed in due course

Comment: ok, sorry, haven't seen ;)

Comment: Wait, did you just mass retag everything? I don't agree with that. I think it's ok for C++1y to remain on questions that applied to stuff that didn't actually make it, or that changed in between. We had the same with C++0x. The tag remains in a few questions for which tagging with C++11 is wrong because they don't refer to things that ended up in C++11. (Granted, one could argue that such questions are now obsolete and borderline useless but that's another matter)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes well; dammit; that's a pain. If I have goofed in a bad way, let me know; I'll have to do some work to undo it... (it is much easier to merge than to unmerge)

Comment: Don't worry. There aren't that many questions so we can go through them manually and fix it.