# The C#-6.0 tag is wrong

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Microsoft has released several preview compilers and documents relating to

> language features currently planned for the next version of C#

That future version will be C# 6.0, evidently planned for release alongside the final version of Visual Studio 2014.  But people have created and used [c#-6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-6.0) for all this technology preview stuff which does not match the final C# 6.0 specification and even has half a dozen [different flavors](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CSharp%20Language%20Design%20Notes&referringTitle=Documentation).

For C++, we solved this problem by using [c++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) and [c++1y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1y) for the pre-Standard drafts and implementations and [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) or [c++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) for the final authoritative feature set.

Would it make sense to similarly differentiate the C# technology previews from the "real" C#-6 questions which are surely not too far off, and can only be confused by pre-release information masquerading as applicable to C# 6.0?  Is [c#6-preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%236-preview) a good name or can you suggest something better?

Should we try to have different tags for the different preview milestones?  Or just put a note in the tag wiki instructing posters to be very clear about which milestone they are asking about?

Comment: In general, I dislike preview and beta tags because they become obsolete, and maintaining them is a small nightmare.

Comment: In particular, the claim made in the wiki that "C# 6 is shipped with the Roslyn End-User Preview" is completely bogus.  The End User Preview is not being kept up to date with language changes [{source}](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Looking around, but I can't find anything official on the naming. What's Microsoft's official versioning on this? If they just say "C# 6.0" I think it will cause lots of confusion in three months since they aren't even calling it a preview.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: What's the alternative?  Ban asking questions about preview and beta versions?

Comment: @StevenV: Microsoft alternately uses vNext and "language features currently planned for the next version of C#"

Comment: We've done this before with prior versions of C#, and it's never been a problem.  Microsoft is unlikely to change the name from C# 6.0 to something else when they release, so the only peril might be discussing features that don't actually make the final cut.  And the fact that the end user preview doesn't keep pace with the language changes doesn't particularly bother those of us who use C# on a regular basis.  If the Tag Wiki bothers you, just change it to make it more accurate, but please don't include advice about asking questions about unreleased features on some `v-next` tag.

Comment: I'm in favour of keeping the tag as c#-6.0, personally. Yes, it will change a bit over time - but then so do plain unversioned-language questions. (The correct answer to a question about whether Java supports lambda expressions used to be no; it's now yes.) I suspect the language will stabilize before there are *lots* of questions about C# 6 (I've hardly seen any so far) so I don't think it's going to cause a big long-term problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Then can you propose a change to (or simply edit) the tag wiki that would make it appropriate for both preview and final version questions?  Because right now it's promulgating the idea that the end-user preview and CTP are implementations of the final language spec, and users are acting on that information by not including specifics of which preview they're looking at :(

Comment: @Ben: Slight correction: [tag:c++14] is already created and [tag:c++1y] was made a synonym. Still, they are reasonably comparable... this time. I think.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Ah, I missed the announcement about the vote, which just happened this week.  The synonymization is an error, though, is there any trail to discover who implemented that?  There doesn't appear to have been discussion on meta :(

Comment: @BenVoigt: You could look for the synonym-creator... Still, it could be reversed yet, as few new questions arrived in the interim. But you would need fast consensus or a mod-action.

Comment: Will look at the tag wiki when I get the chance.

Comment: What's wrong with changing the tag to `c#-6.0-tech-preview`? Keep it agnostic of preview versions. While some suggestions might come and go I don't think most people will be too concerned about specific versions of the preview.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm the synonym creator. There was a tag clean-up initiated by me and Lounge<C++>. [tag:c++0x] and [tag:c++11] are synonymised as well and have been for ~3 years.

Comment: @Rapptz: After posting that comment I found out that questions tagged with synonyms can remember which variant was originally used.  That's probably a reasonable behavior for questions concerning draft rules.  Unfortunately [a diamond mod performed a mass retag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269437/103167), losing that information.  Really I think the best thing would be separate tags with links between the tag wikis.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yep a mod merged the tags. However we already cleaned up (most of) the mess because there weren't many questions to retag manually. FWIW, I agree with Robert that these questions are obsolete.

Comment: @Rapptz: Obsolete?  Well, maybe not always.  Some "removed" features got bumped for reconsideration in future versions (especially *concepts*); losing  Q&A about those would be a shame.  But so would pretending that all answers given prior to the vote are applicable to the final Standard language.